# Resetting skew/perspective/warp etc. on Smart Object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, filter

Is there a way to reset the skew or perspective effect applied to a smart object?

Setting the warp setting in free transform from custom to none shows no effect.
Otherwise I have to export 50 smart Objects by hand :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hate to say it.. but you can't. Transformations, other than scale, permanently alter the SO.

You can always double-click to open the SO, then drag-drop that layer to the document again and recreate a straight SO. But I realize this doesn't help when having to export many files.

Comment: It's soo sad :(

Comment: I can't believe it's 2018 and this still hasn't been addressed by Adobe. It's so obvious that non-destructive transforms should have the ability to be reset.

Answer (score 2):

To reset a warp:

1. Start Transform Context - Ctrl+T or Apple+T
2. Enable Warp sub menu
3. Set Warp to anything other than Custom or None
4. Set Bend to 0
5. Set Warp to none
6. Apply

To reset transforms just zero out the rotation and set scales to 100. If the object has been skewed then you're out of luck, drag objects from SO back into the scene and make a new copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit apple+T to transform the smart object again, tranform options pop up at the top of the screen. If you orinally changed the scale, the scaling changes will appear in the percentages. Simply type in 100% in both to bring it back to full size. If you warped it, click the warp button and select "None" from the drop down menu at left, restoring it to it's original shape. It'd be nice if there was a simple button to press to reset it, but for now there's just this.

Not sure why selecting "none" isn't helping you. Maybe there was a transformation made prior to converting it to a smart object? In my experience (albeit limited), this resets any transformations I've made.

Comment: Yes for all transformations on smart objects but skew and perspective your answer is right. Setting warp to none did not reset these things.

Answer (score 1):

I created script which can solve it. (only perspective is not fully supported)
[Download here: Untransform 1.0](http://bereza.cz/ps/index.html#undeform)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only option then is to go to **Edit -> Transform -> Scale** and drag the corners until both the object's horizontal and vertical edges are completely straight. Then you can set the width and height to 100% and the object should be back to normal.

Although there is no button for resetting warp transformations, you could create one.
Just go to **Window -> Actions** and use the box that pops up to record your actions. Then, in the top right corner there is a button from where you can select `Button Mode` to show the recorded actions as buttons. Then, all you need to do is to click on an action button and the changes are made automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a trick :

Convert the object to smart object, then, do it one more time (convert the smart object to smart object). For some reason, it allows you to juggle with a single angle.

Can't tell you why...

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+t
right click and set it to Wrap
then clik on "reset the warp"
you are done.

[image]

Comment: Since which PS Version is this possible? I am currently running CC2019 and there isn't this button ...

Answer (score 0):

**2021 Update:**

Photoshop v22.4.3 has this feature built-in.

In the layers panel, right-click on the layer text (not the thumbnail) and click Reset Transform

Answer (score -1):

Answering an old question with some updated practices:

**Simple Instructions:**

Open distorted smart object and save it as its own PSB file. Go to original smart object, right click and select "replace contents", find PSB file you saved.

**Detailed Instructions:**

1. Double click on Smart Object (S.O.) to open it up as a Smart Object Contents file.
2. Click File > Save As to save the good, unaltered, S.O. as its own .PSB file.
3. Close this S.O. Contents file.
4. Go back to your original file with the distorted S.O.
5. Right Click the S.O. > Click "Replace Contents"
6. Find the .PSB file with the original S.O. content that you saved in Step 2.

Comment: wouldn't it then just replace the content and stay distorted, since the SmartObject is still distorted?

Answer (score -1):

Fastest way.

1. Double click on Smart Object (S.O.) to open it up as a Smart Object
   Contents file.
2. Select all your layers and create a new S.O.
3. Duplicate the new S.O. onto the original image.
4. DONE.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the smart object.
2. Group and drag all smart object layers into source file.
3. Save as new smart object.